# Given Import Error , Even I'm already imported model class?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a models.py like this

```
from notifications.models import SignupInfoEmail

    class Request(models.Model):
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
        modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
        last_contacted = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)

        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        email = models.EmailField()
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
        zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5,null=True, blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
           return str(self.email)

        def send_info(self):
           first_name = self.first_name
           price = self.plan().calculate_price()
           #from notifications.models import SignupInfoEmail
           if self.status.upper() == "NEW":
              self.status = "info sent"
           self.last_contacted = datetime.datetime.now()
           self.save()
           return SignupInfoEmail.objects.send_info(self, self.email, first_name, price, self.info_url())
```

When I'm calling send_info function it is giving **ImportError: cannot import name SignupInfoEmail** even if i'm already imported SignupInfoEmail from notification model.I tried by removing the import statement from top of the file and wrote that import statement in send_info function(commented statement) then works fine.Why? What is the reason?

Comment: You have a circular dependency; probably notification.models is importing whatever this models file is.

Comment: Yes Daniel, I'm importing this model.py in notification.models. So is there any solution to keep all these import statement at top of the models.py ?

Comment: @vijaykumark  `import` is an executable statement, and is executed (as well as all other top-level executable statements - including `class` and `def`) the first time the module is imported for the current process. This imply you _can not_ have two modules importing each other (at least with `import` statements at the top level in both).